# Why is the fetch statement in my react app resulting in two calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Can anybody please explain to me why the fetch statement is resulting in 2 API calls? Both the chrome console and dev tools > network tab is showing two versions. The following is the code that I am using.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './contact.css';

const App = () => {

  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=3")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));

  return (

    <>
      {
        contacts.map(contact => (
          <ContactCard
            avatar="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
            name={contact.name}
            email={contact.email}
            age={contact.age}
          />
        ))
      }
    </>
  )
};


const ContactCard = props => {

  const [showAge, setShowAge] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="contact-card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="profile" />
      <div className="user-details">
        <p>Name: {props.name}</p>
        <p>Email: {props.email}</p>

        <button onClick={() => setShowAge(!showAge)}>{!showAge ? 'Show' : 'Hide'} Age</button>

        {
          showAge && <p>Age: {props.age}</p>
        }

      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Look at the type of call, is one an OPTIONS request? That's part of CORS.

Comment: OPTIONS is the CORS pre-flight - though, I can't see why your code as shown would trigger pre-flight - just tested, it's not going to be OPTIONS - it's going to be something react related

Comment: The `App` is executed multiple times, if you want to call `fetch` only once when the component is mounted, use `useEffect(() => fetch(..), [])`, the `[]` is important, it ensures that the function passed to `useEffect` is run only once on component mount.

Comment: @Titus For some reason, removing the `[]` at the end, still seems to work... As in, now I am only making 1 call! Do you know why?

Comment: Without the `[]`, the function will run on mount and on every update but since the `App` component doesn't have any properties, it runs only on mount. You should get used to using `[]` if you want to do something only on mount to avoid bugs.

Comment: @Titus Aah okay. So basically, it will work in my particular case even without `[]` but ideally it's better to use `[]` to avoid problems later.. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. My previous comment is incomplete, the function will also run when you update the state (calling `setContacts` for example) not just when you update the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const App = () => {

  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  // the issue is here, each time the component renders this statement will be exectuted
  fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=3")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));

  // if you want to execute code after component is mounted into dom, use useEffect
  // like this

   useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=3")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
   }, []) // the second param for useEffect is dependencies array, pass an empty array if you want your effect to run only once (which is equivalent to componentDidMount in react class based components)
  return (

    <>
      {
        contacts.map(contact => (
          <ContactCard
            avatar="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
            name={contact.name}
            email={contact.email}
            age={contact.age}
          />
        ))
      }
    </>
  )
};
```

Comment: Although, removing the `[]` in the end still seems to work!

Comment: @Grateful it will work, but again it will make the network request each time the component is rendered (it will be exactly the same code, as if it was not wrapped in useEffect)

Comment: Hmmm... Strange! Because as soon as I remove the `useEffect` it goes back to making 2 calls. Whereas, if I continue with `useEffect` it works perfectly... And the chrome console and network tab is only showing 1 API call unlike before!

Comment: I would really like to get to the bottom of this if possible!

Comment: @Grateful well if you dont pass the dependencies array, the function in useEffect will be called every time the component renders (if it rendered one time it will be called one time), so either your component now only render once for another reason, or you are not aware of second request - assuming you indeed removed the dependencies array. 
Either case here is react documentation confirming what i said https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect